# Is there any api for getting the value of UseCanonicalName in Apache WebServer?

Tags: c++, apache, webserver, httpd.conf

We need to check the value of UseCanonicalName in httpd.conf in Apache Webserver(any version) from an application using an api. I have googled for it and couldn't find any api related to it. Please help.
TIA

Comment: just to clarify the question: you want to ask the running instance of apache about its settings? (so you do not have to do any parsing of the config files)

Comment: No I don't have any parsing mechanism for config file rather I am trying to get the UseCanonicalName value from running instance.

Answer (score 0):

Query the `httpd.conf` file for `/UseCanonicalName/`.

Comment: How? What would a smaple query look like?